# Can I send push notification without passing by an endpoint ? Angular 6

Tags: angular, push-notification, signalr, service-worker

I want to push notification to desktop and mobile in an environment without network just in local :

I'm already using Signalr to display real time data

Can I use it with a service worker and Notification API to show push notification even if the browser is closed ?

or any other solution ?

Comment: Are you referring to local push notification? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/

Comment: server sent event with service stack and use servicestack js client

Comment: @FatehMohamed can you give an explanation or an example ?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya it's an Angular app not Ionic

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular, not Angular and Ionic or Angular Mobile (meaning native apps). So to do Push notifications you must make your app into a PWA (progressive web app) using service workers.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/

just a side note, the user will have to visit your site x amount of times before downloading the page will be available, and only then can push notifications be active.

Not all desktops support this, but most phones do now that Apple has excepted PWA use.

Comment: Yes I'm already using PWA but the problem the push notification pass by an endpoint for example FCM for chrome so my app should be connected to the network for it's can work ; in my case the environment which i will deploy my app there's not network , so my question was if there's any way to push notification without using endpoint ?

Comment: Yes, just generate the notifications on the front end using a service, that link above still applies. It's all local. The only requirement is that the user must be able to visit the site x amount of times, and that you have all the right flags in your pwa like caching, local download, etc

Comment: You mean to use Notification API just in front end ? , but how can recieve notifications when the browser is closed ?

Comment: Yes. Service workers run in the background, meaning they run when applications are closed unless the user has disabled them. Service workers run on the OS clock and utilize the computers ram to handle actions while the browser is closed. note that pwa's don't work on all Desktop OS's, but they do on most smartphones. Use Ionic if you want them to work well on desktops

Comment: can you give a documentation or a tutorial because I tried before and i did not receive notification when the browser is closed

Comment: first, that is a separate question. your question was essentially, 'is it possible?' The answer is yes. Second, are you talking about mobile or desktop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180365/discussion-between-dev-and-fussinhussin).